# How to take all elements from a list

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

I want to take all data which satisfies a condition from my hive db.

I used this code to get the required data:

```
var reqdata = task_DB.values.where((TaskModel) => TaskModel.date == DateFormat('EEE,d/m/y').parseStrict(_datestr)).toList().toString
```

Now I want to take all data which satisfies that condition and print it and use it in a list view, but I, am not able to get the data that I want.

I, am stuck with this for a long time, Any help would be useful

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, Can you write the full code? To fully understand your problem

Comment: remove toString

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Rahul So if I removed ` .toString` it returns `` Instance of Task model'`` task model is the hive model which has all the data required.

Comment: right. you need to work with that model object.